# How to make collection of buttons in Xcode with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, collections

How to make a collection of buttons, in Android it's a gridview. How to make a two collection and how to move bottom button to over collection of buttons?  This is the image of what I ask =>

[image: Click me!]

Collectionview is a true solution? or what UIView should I use?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! Please review our guide about [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Some extra details like existing code and things you've already tried would help a lot.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could try using a `horizontal stack view`. Or if you want a collection try a ui collection view embedded inside of that view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StackView and add yours buttons, but create stackview dynamic is complex (Stackview horizontal with vertical like a collectionview).

CollectionView in iOS is the same GridView in Android. They're do the same thing.